# AWS/SSL certificate(s) for Nginx setup inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have a dockerized django app (cookiecutter) and I want to configure nginx inside of a docker container, so I can deploy it to an EC2 instance. For that I need ssl certificates.

The process to get a ssl certificate with Let's Encrypt like it is recommended everywhere seems to be a complicated task when you use docker, nginx and EC2. I tried it and can't get passed the error I'm linking below.

So I was wondering if there is a way to configure nginx with an AWS certificate. I read that AWS certificates are free but can't be downloaded (https://serverfault.com/questions/822035/). So my question is threefold:

a) Can I configure nginx without https, get a free certificate for my AWS EC2 instance and then run my app on that server with https?

b) If the answer is yes, how could I configure my nginx server to serve only http for that?

c) If I buy a certificate from a CA can I use it to configure my nginx and will it be transportable if I move my app (to Digital Ocean or Azure or sth)?

I am by no means an expert in most of these technologies and fighting myself through a jungle here. Very grateful for help, hints, tips, suggestions and guidance. Thanks very much in advance. I happily provide more code if needed.

Tutorial I tried but can't solve my error:
https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

Tutorial for nginx with docker and let's encrypt I wanted to follow if there is no easier and quicker solution: https://www.humankode.com/ssl/how-to-set-up-free-ssl-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-using-docker-and-nginx

Error with Let's Encrypt:

> > Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem) To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address.